# Extreme values of $2\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\cdot\sin^2 x$ without calculus

Tags: trigonometry

> To find the extreme values of
> $$2\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\cdot\sin^2 x$$

I Have not learnt calculus yet but this is a question within our syllabus .which made me to think if this can be done with it .

I am not able approach this problem any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via AM-GM,
$$2\cos^2\frac x2 \cdot \sin^2 x = (\cos x + 1)(1-\cos^2 x) = \frac 12 (1 + \cos x)(1+\cos x) (2- 2\cos x) \le \frac 12 \left( \frac{1+\cos x + 1 + \cos x + 2 - 2\cos x}{3}\right)^3=\frac 12 \left( \frac 43\right)^3 = \frac{32}{27}$$

where $"=" \iff 1+\cos x = 2- 2 \cos x \iff\cos x = \frac 13.$

Answer (score 0):

Writing $x=2y$

$$\cos y\sin2y=2(1-\sin^2y)\sin y$$

$$\dfrac{2\sin^2y+1-\sin^2y+1-\sin^2y}3\ge\sqrt[3]{2\sin^2y(1-\sin^2y)^2}$$

$$\implies\left(\sqrt2\sin y(1-\sin^2y)\right)^{2/3}\le\dfrac23$$